# How can I get the distinct ids where ALL rows match a certain criteria in GBQ?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm querying a database to get the distinct ids where all the rows with each id match the criteria. For example, I would like to query the table below to get the distinct id where all values are truue. In this case, I would only return a single row with the id of 1.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | false |
| 2 | true |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | false |
| 3 | false |
| 3 | false |

Expected result

| ColumnA |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |

Currently, I have a query such as this

```
select 
  columnA
from
  table
group by
  columnA
having
  (count(columnB = false) = 0)
```

But I end up returning no data at all. Not an error, just nothing matching my query. This is an example with dummy data, but the actual DB is quite large so I would expect lots of data back.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

consider to use [LOGICAL_AND](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#logical_and) function.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 column_a, true column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 column_a, true column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 column_a, false column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 column_a, true column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 column_a, true column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 column_a, false column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 column_a, false column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 column_a, false column_b
)
SELECT column_a
  FROM sample_table
 GROUP BY 1
HAVING LOGICAL_AND(column_b) IS TRUE;


+----------+
| column_a |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

Comment: just `HAVING LOGICAL_AND(column_b) ` will also work - :o)